# color td based on object field value Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have a table, and I want based on a property, to color rows like this:
If `account` is the same, color them with gray, and if not, color them with blue. Here is my code:

```
func() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.List.length; i++) {
      if (this.List[i].account == this.List[i + 1].account) {
        this.List[i].color = "#f2f3f4"
      } else {
        if (this.List[i].account != this.List[i + 1].account && this.List[i].color != "#f2f3f4") {
          this.List[i].color = "rgba(173, 216, 230, 0.35)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

but it's not working properly. How can I modify the code? [Here is a working blitzstack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q9siga)

I also get this error: (I guess it's from `List[i + 1]`)

> ERROR Error: Cannot read property 'account' of undefined

Comment: is every object in this.List has property account ?

Comment: You need to check for the last element, there won't be any `List[i+1]`

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < this.List.length; i++)` should be  ` for (let i = 0; i < this.List.length - 1; i++)` so that `List[i + 1]` resolves to a non-undefined object

Comment: I would suggest `forEach()` internal iterator to avoid such errors

Comment: accept the answer if you are satisfied

Comment: When looking at the answers, I think your definition of "same accounts " leads to mistake. Please clarify. Are you talking about "consecutive rows" ? "same account as logged in user"? "accounts which appear more than once in the table regardless row position"?

Comment: Let's say the rows are already sorted inside this table, based on account. So my definition of 'same account' is consecutive rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your code

```
func() {

    const d  = this.List.map(e => e.account);

    this.List.forEach(user => {
       const length = this.List.filter(s => s.account === user.account).length;
       user.color = length >= 2 ? "#f2f3f4" : "rgba(173, 216, 230, 0.35)";
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I wanted!

Comment: Actually this is not working very good, if I add 2 more rows at the end with the same account, they will be colored with `blue`, instead of gray.

Comment: have you tried to rerun the function after adding the accounts

Comment: please update your stackblitz with your requirement so that we can help better

Comment: updated the answer `length >= 2`. missed the equal sign

Answer (score 2):

Basic index mistake.

You are looping over the whole array (from `0` to `this.List.length`) and then try to access `this.List[i + 1]`.

Loop from `0` to `this.List.length - 1`

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.List.length - 1; i++) {
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the error, but the rows still have wrong colors.

Comment: @Tenzolinho when you mentioned "wrong color", what "same accounts" means? Looking at your code, it seems that "same account" means "account of line i === account of line i+1".

Comment: @Grégory Elhaimer Agreed with your answer but you need to color the last row :)

Comment: @Tenzolinho, please be more precise about what "same account" means.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only valid if the requirement is:

- All rows which have either the previous or next row with the same account must be colored in grey. Otherwise, they are colored in blue
- A single row is in blue (cannot have same account with some other row)
- An account which appears multiple times but non in consecutive rows are colored in blue
- rows are assumed unsorted (so sorting rows again will make rows color change)

Additionally, it is good to know that in JavaScript [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is supposed to follow array order.

> forEach() calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized (i.e. on sparse arrays).

The idea is:

- Loop through all elements but *order should not matter!*
- If the previous or next row has the same account, then apply the rules above

```
  func() {
    // Empty list
    if(this.List.length === 0){
      return
    }
    // A single entry cannot have "same account"
    if(this.List.length === 1){
      this.List[0].color = "rgba(173, 216, 230, 0.35)"
      return
    }

    this.List.forEach((entry, i) => {
      // beware of edge case (first and last rows)
      const sameAccountPrev = i > 0 
          ? entry.account === this.List[i-1].account 
          : false
      const sameAccountNext = i < this.List.length -1
          ? entry.account === this.List[i+1].account
          : false
      entry.color = sameAccountPrev || sameAccountNext
          ? "#f2f3f4"
          : "rgba(173, 216, 230, 0.35)"
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to solve this would be to hash the usernames into a color. That way every two rows with the same user would have the same color.

Of course you would have less control over which color would be used.